# Datastax Java driver to autodiscover all the nodes for specific datacenter in its connection pool?

Tags: java, cassandra, astyanax, datastax-java-driver

I have recently started using `Cassandra` in our `Production environment`. We have a `24 node cluster` with `replication factor of 4`. Meaning `2 copies` will be there in `each datacenter`. So that means we have a single cross colo cluster with `24 nodes` which means `12 nodes in SLC colo` and `12 nodes in PHX colo`.

I am using `Astyanax client` currently to write the data in `Cassandra database`. And I know Astyanax client has this feature to autodiscover all the nodes in PHX colo or SLC colo of cassandra in its connection pooling but not all of the nodes.

In Astyanax we can use something like below -

```
setLocalDatacenter("DC1")
```

Now we are planning to use Datastax Java driver. And I am not sure whether Datastax java driver has this feature or not to autodiscover all the cassandra nodes in its connection pool only for specific datacenter and not all the datacenters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The driver will discover all the nodes in your cluster, you want to change your load balancing policy in your client code. Specifically you want to use the dc aware load balancing policy.

http://www.datastax.com/drivers/java/apidocs/com/datastax/driver/core/policies/DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy.html

Comment: Does this mean Datastax will be able to filter out all the nodes basis on local datacenter?

Comment: From the link: " In other words, this policy guarantees that no host in a remote datacenter will be queried unless no host in the local datacenter can be reached."